# Cannot use `getpagesize()` call to set a global variable in C

Tags: c, global, paging

With the following code

```
#include <unistd.h>

int a = getpagesize();

int main() {
    return a;
}
```

I receive the following compilation error

```
3:1: error: initializer element is not constant
```

What is an "initializer element", and why does it need to be constant?  Does that relate to the `const` qualifier?

Comment: Ummm ... That would be because the initializer `getpagesize()` is not constant.  It's a function call.

Comment: The compiler can't know that `getpagesize()` gives nearly always the same value (and you could in theory make a Linux kernel where it might change, eg for huge page size support)

Comment: Execution of your program begins on entry to the `main` function. There's no time for the call to `getpagesize()` to be executed.

Answer (score 4):

The value used to initialize global variables needs to be determined at compile time. The return value of a function (in C, at least) won't be evaluated until run time. So something like:

```
int a = 4;
```

is OK, but:

```
int a = somefunction();
```

is not. In C++ you can have `constexpr` functions, but in C you can't.

If you must do something like this, you can always use:

```
int a;

int main(void) {
    a = getpagesize();

    /*  Rest of your program  */
}
```

Obviously you can't make your global `const` doing this (since you can only set the value of a `const` variable at initialization, and you can't initialize globals with functions). Frankly, there's probably no reason why you can't just call `getpagesize()` when you need it and forget about a global variable altogether - unless you call it a billion times, you won't notice the overhead. If you must have a global variable, then just don't make it `const`.

If immutability is an absolute requirement, and the problem is avoiding an expensive function call rather than avoiding function calls altogether, then one option is to replace it with an inexpensive function call, like so:

```
int poor_mans_global(void) {
    static int a = -1;
    if ( a == -1 ) {
        a = getpagesize();   /*  Only call the expensive function once  */
    }
    return a;
}
```

and call `poor_mans_global()` instead of using your global variable. Note that this example is illustrative only, and doesn't imply that `getpagesize()` is an expensive function call.

A final option is to package all your code that needs access to this global into a separate translation unit, and make the global `static`, i.e. file scope rather than truly global. The benefits of `const` - which are never all *that* great to begin with, in C - decrease dramatically when you can exert tight control over which code gets to access that variable.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  Do you think there's a way to get page size put into a global variable, preferably immutable?